# XL6009 control with MCU

Tags: microcontroller, step-up

I want to control some 20-30w led chip with mcu.They need 30-32V so i need step up for that. And thought about that cheap modules with XL6009. Is it possible to control them with PWM on EN pin?

Comment: Please link to the datasheet of the module. Without datasheet, we can't tell what it does, and then the right assumption is that it can't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without having a look at the circuit, we can't help you with what component to choose. Regarding the XL6009, if you have a look at the [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.fr/datasheet-pdf/view/1132228/XLSEMI/XL6009.html) you can see that there is an enable pin :

[image]

You can also have a look at some typical application circuits to help you design yours.

Comment: yes something like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/182804193348?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=3n_0fgpTRpm&sssrc=4429486&ssuid=&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY) so i expect that would use typical schematic from datasheet. so if i would use pwm signal from mcu on EN pin would that result in 0-30v pwm output?

Comment: if so would that be ok to dimm [that](https://www.ebay.com/itm/163753172357?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=U6La0sn8TLe&sssrc=4429486&ssuid=&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY) led?

Comment: @useRR It should do the job under some conditions. Firstly you will have to provide a DC input voltage  to the IN+ pad and tune your potentiometer to get a 30V output. After that you will need your PWM signal to be 0-5V to use it as an enable signal. Secondly your PWM as to be under 400kHz for this component since it's the maximum switching frequency of the XL6009.

Comment: Do i need to add some filter or  its not necessary?

Comment: @useRR without the datasheet of the PCB you wanna buy on ebay, it's hard to tell if there are already some filters or not. If not, it would be great to filter your IN+.